# Magento 2 - How to add columns to Sales order products grid?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, orders, grid

In magento 2 I need to add columns (stock, status, brand) in this admin grid :

```
Sales > Order > Create new order > Select Product Grid
```

Do you know how to achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid.php` and add the column in _prepareColumns function just like i have added the column of name custom. This file is responsible for `Sales > Order > Create new order > Select Product Grid`.

```
  /**
     * Prepare collection to be displayed in the grid
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        $attributes = $this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes();
        $store = $this->getStore();

        /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->productCollectionProvider->getCollectionForStore($store);
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(
            $attributes
        );
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
            'type_id',
            $this->_salesConfig->getAvailableProductTypes()
        );

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare columns
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'index' => 'entity_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Product'),
                'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Product::class,
                'index' => 'name'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'column_css_class' => 'price',
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => $this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
                'rate' => $this->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()),
                'index' => 'price',
                'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Price::class
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_products',
            [
                'header' => __('Select'),
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_products',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'qty',
            [
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'header' => __('Quantity'),
                'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Qty::class,
                'name' => 'qty',
                'inline_css' => 'qty',
                'type' => 'input',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index' => 'qty'
            ]
        );
//extra column.
        $this->addColumn(
            'custom',
            [
                'header' => __('Custom'),
                'index' => 'custom'
            ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

Comment: My new columns are added in first position. Do you kow how to change this order ?
I try attributes like "sort_order" but it doesn't work...

Comment: I was wondering if you could make it with a plugin instead of preference for ?